# The Battery dell inspiron 15 - 3521 do not charge and can not be identified

Tags: boot, dell, power-management, laptop, battery

I bought a new laptop battery but the device does not recognize it and does not charge it.
my device:
laptop dell inspiron 15 3521
bios-release-date:
07/31/2015
os ubuntu:22.04
I tried to update the bios with usb but there is no option bios flash update.
I need help please help me

Comment: this is not an Ubuntu problem, it's a BIOS issue and you need to update the BIOS (if possible; if you can't then the battery just won't work, sorry).

Comment: This is more a hardware question than a specific Ubuntu question. The device does not recognize your new battery. Therefor I think that this question should not be asked on this site.

Comment: https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000131486/update-the-dell-bios-in-a-linux-or-ubuntu-environment Your laptop is quite possibly too old to update with a "flash firmware" button. You may need to update from inside Windows (or FreeDos, as detailed in this link).